# Can I use a different filesystem type for the boot partition?

Tags: boot, archlinux

I downloaded the Archlinux arm `.img` file for the Raspberry Pi and installed it onto my SD card.

Is it possible to use a different partition instead of `FAT16` that is in the `.img`? Or will the GPU not detect it at all?

I ask because it would be a huge performance boost if I could use squashfs as the boot partition.

Comment: Welcome to RaspberryPi.SE :) I hope you don't mind, I added the `archlinux` tag to your post to help other Arch users like ourselves find it.

Comment: Technically it's Archlinux arm but thanks anyway for inserting the tag. :D

Comment: Don't worry, the ARM architecture is implied.

Comment: @Haskeller Why don't you want it to be FAT? It is a small partition, with no writes.

Comment: File permissions,time stamps, and read performance improvements(loading kernel).

Comment: @Haskeller Do you have any details of `squashfs` boosting performance?

Comment: @Jivings newer benchmark https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/6/8/230

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the only mention of the boot partition I can find in the [chip documentation](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf):

> The split between ARM and GPU memory is selected by installing one of
>   the supplied  start*.elf files as start.elf in the FAT32 boot
>   partition of the SD card.

Therefore I assume it will only read FAT.

Just found this on the [Raspberry Pi forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2567):

> There is firmware on the SOC that you will not be able to touch.  It
>   is pre-programed from the factory.  And yes it is required to boot,
>   and this is why the first partition has to be FAT because this is how
>   the firmware is designed.  You only need a FAT partition big enough to
>   hold a bootloader of some type.

Comment: Does Broadcom have any other versions of GPU firmware that will load the Archlinux arm kernel on a filesystem besides FAT?

Comment: I assume the root partition isn't FAT?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Root partition is EXT4.

Comment: @Haskeller: Not as far as I am aware. What is your use case?

Comment: @Jivings I thought it would be...

Comment: EXT4: has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize. Why does it have journaling on? Thats so bad for the SD card.

Comment: @Haskeller turn it off then. That's what I've done. Generally the Arch image is set with defaults.

Comment: so it cannot be converted to ext4 for shutdown OK with losing power, does it? thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in the most literal sense, the partition could be FAT32, instead of FAT16. The Debian image uses FAT32.

Comment: Pretty sure Arch is also FAT32 and OP was mistaken.

Comment: @Jivings Nope, it is definitely FAT16. You can use `piimg list`.